# Materialized views in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb, materialized-views

Is there a way to create materialized views in PouchDB? I want this because data is almost static, but the user makes queries quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quiet like an materialized view.
You change data, User executes Query, PouchDB works around the indexes, after first 'indexing' everything works like a Materialized View, Indexed in Memory, until something change and we update the indexing on next query. Over and over.

https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html

> Persistent queries Persistent queries are much faster, and are the
>   intended way to use the query() API in your production apps. To use
>   persistent queries, there are two steps.
>
> First, you create a design document, which describes the map function
>   you would like to use:

```
// document that tells PouchDB/CouchDB
// to build up an index on doc.name

var ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/my_index',
  views: {
    by_name: {
      map: function (doc) { emit(doc.name); }.toString()
    }
  }
};
// save it
pouch.put(ddoc).then(function () {
  // success!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error (maybe a 409, because it already exists?)
});
```

Then you actually query it, by using the name you gave the design document when you saved it:

```
db.query('my_index/by_name').then(function (res) {
  // got the query results
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error
});
```

Note that, the first time you query, it will be quite slow because the index isn't built until you query it. To get around this, you can do an empty query to kick off a new build:

```
db.query('my_index/by_name', {
  limit: 0 // don't return any results
}).then(function (res) {
  // index was built!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error
});
```

Comment: +1 for explicitly stating how to initialize a 'new' index (I'm trying to prepare an imported pouchdb-dump so I want to build all indexes too before telling the user everything is ready)